# Flutter: Late Initialization Error for Fire Base Storage Image Upload

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to allow signed in users upload profile pictures to their homepages. Before I added the `uploadImage` function to my code, I was able to login as a user successfully and print the user's email at the top of the page to prove they were actually signed in. Now that I have added the profile picture uploader code, when I log in as a user I get the following red screen error:

```
LateInitializedError: Field 'imageUrl' has not been initialized.
```

I have given the imageUrl the `Late modifier` thinking this would allow the code to run and have the variable assigned later in the run but that did not fix the issue. I need help letting the variable be okay with being null until the user can upload their own picture.  Here's the video I was watching to learn how to start this process:

[Flutter Image Upload Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvRpzyBYBbA&t=577s)

Here's my code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:commentaries/net/authentication.dart';
import 'package:commentaries/ui/nav.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserPageState createState() => _UserPageState();
}

class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
  User user = auth.currentUser!;
  late String imageUrl; // A: USER PROFILE PICTURE

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('${user.email}'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          (imageUrl != null)
              ? Image.network(imageUrl)
              : const Placeholder(
                  fallbackHeight: 200.0, fallbackWidth: double.infinity),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 20.0,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('Upload Image'),
            onPressed: () => uploadImage(),
          ),
          // A: LOGOUT USER HERE
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Logout'),
            // this removes all previous routes and returns signed out user to the home tab (sign in screen)
            onPressed: () => signOut().then(
              (_) => Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Nav()),
                  (Route<dynamic> route) => false),
            ),
            // onPressed:(){
            //   auth.signOut();
            //   Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Nav()));
            // },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  uploadImage() async {
    final _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    final _picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile image;
    // A: Check permissions
    await Permission.photos.request();
    var permissionStatus = await Permission.photos.status;
    if (permissionStatus.isGranted) {
      // A: Select Image
      // A: future picked file, add await clarification
      image = (await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery)) as PickedFile;
      var file = File(image.path);
      if (image != null) {
        // A: Upload to firebase
        var snapshot = await _storage
          .ref()
          .child('folderName/imageName') // will create folder: folderName and image: imageName
          .putFile(file);
        var downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        setState(() {
          imageUrl = downloadUrl;
        });
      } else {
        print('No path recieved, no image detected');
      }
    } else {
      print('App is not permitted to access photo gallery');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just change `late String imageUrl` to `String? imageUrl`.

Comment: Hi @adamcapjones, did you have a chance to try what  rickimaru suggested?

Comment: Yes, this fixed my issue.  Thank you, I was not aware of this as a feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting rickimaru's solution as a Community wiki for visibility:

You need to replace the `late String imageUrl` with `String? imageUrl` to fix the initialization error.